# Life table probabilities

Tags: probability, mortality

I am using 2007's Social Security Life Table: http://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html

I would like to use the table to generate a number for each scenario I ran. This number represents the remaining life (in years) scenario n will live. The way I plan to do this is to first input an age 'x' let say age 60. I get the corresponding number on column 'Number of Lives' which is 85,227. (This simply reveals that out of 100K people, 85,227 survived) Next, I randomly select one integer from 1:100K and if it is less than 85,227, then this scenario will continue on to next year else this case will die off. I repeat this process, at each age get the corresponding number from column 'Number of Lives' and so on ...

I want to know if such method is sound from a probability perspective. Does it violate any axioms. Do I still preserve the underlying population distribution of the table? Any better ways of doing it?

Comment: most life table comes with a column that tells you the expected life at that age.

Comment: What you're describing, in essence, is an [accept reject algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah if you choose a radix of $100,000$, then $l_{x+t}/l_x$ is the probability of somebody aged $x$ living at least $t$ more years.

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to say that there is anything wrong with the approach but I do not understand why you need to simulate.  The life table is a discrete form of survival analysis where instead of looking at survival data in continuous time you group by a time interval like years.  The method is often referred to as the Cutler-Ederer method due to a famous paper by those authors. It is essentially an interval form of Kaplan-Meier (at least there is an analogy that can be made).

If age is a covariate that you want to use in constructing tables, you could do a survival model that uses regression (it could be through a parametric survival model as in the SAS lifereg procedure or a semiparametric survival model, e.g. the Cox proportional hazard model).  Given data that enable you to fit such a model, I think you could construct your lifetables from such a model.